# List<Object> vs List<dynamic>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a heterogeneous `List` of objects (custom classes). My first thought was to create a `List<ISomeMarkerInterface>` but I quickly learned that this is not what I want. My next thought was `List<dynamic>` and this didn't seem to be a bad idea. However, I was doing some research and came across this [article about boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) and in the example, they're doing basically what I want using `List<Object>`.

Aside from the fact that `dynamic` will be evaluated at runtime and `Object` at compile-time, what is the difference between `List<dynamic>` and `List<Object>`? Aren't they essentially the same thing?

Comment: why do you need to store heterogeneous objects in the same list? Just curious...

Comment: you should look for dynamic vs object , check out this thread, it probably replies your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442821/dynamic-vs-object-type

Comment: I have a class where one of the properties is a collection of items relevant to that class that are not the same type, but are relevant as a group.

Comment: As an aside, can you explain why `ISomeMarkerInterface` was no good?

Comment: `ISomeMarkerInterface` wasn't any good because (and this may just be me) but I was having problems casting back to the actual object to do anything useful. Since marker interfaces have no properties or methods, it was really hard to use in LINQ lambda expressions :\

Comment: If all you want is easy LINQ, have you looked at Enumerable.OfType<T>() with List<Object>?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are 3 "general" types (although not all are real types) in C#: object, var and dynamic.

**Object**

An actual type, like any other type, with one special rule: if a type doesn't inherit, it inherits from *object*. From this, it follows that *all* types inherit from *object*, directly or indirectly.

Emphasis: **object is a type**. An object can be of type *object*, and the type has its methods, like ToString(). Since everything inherits from *object*, everything can be upcast into *object*. When you assign an object to an *object* reference, you are doing upcasting just like when you assign an *Elephant* type object to an *Animal* reference where *Elephant* inherits from *Animal*.

```
SomeType x = new SomeType();
object obj = x;
obj.DoSomething();
```

- *obj* is treated as being of type *object* at compile time, and will be of type *object* at runtime (which is logical, since it is an actual type - *obj* is declared as *object* so can only be of that type)
- *obj.DoSomething()* will cause a compile-time error, as *object* does not have this method, regardless of whether SomeType has it.

**Var**

This is not an actual type, it is merely shorthand for "compiler, figure out the type for me based on the right side of the assignment".

```
SomeType x = new SomeType();
var obj = x;
obj.DoSomething();
```

- *obj* is treated as being of type *SomeType* at compile time, and will be of type *SomeType* at runtime, just as if you had written "SomeType" instead of "var".
- if *SomeType* has a method *DoSomething()*, this code will work
- if *SomeType* doesn't have the method, the code will cause a compile-time error

**Dynamic**

This is a type that tells the compiler to disable compile-time type checking on the variable. An object is treated as having the type *dynamic* at compile-time and run-time.

```
SomeType x = new SomeType();
dynamic obj = x;
obj.DoSomething();
```

- obj is of type *dynamic* at compile and run time
- if *SomeType* has a method *DoSomething()*, this code will work
- if *SomeType* doesn't have the method, the code will compile, but throw an exception at run-time
- note that *dynamic* can cause exceptions very easily if used carelessly:

  ```
  public void f(dynamic x)
  { 
      x.DoSomething();
  }
  ```

This will throw an exception if *x* is of a type that doesn't have the *DoSomething* method, but it will still be possible to call it and pass any object as the parameter without a compile-time error, causing an error that only shows itself at run-time, and possibly only in specific circumstances - a potential bug. So if you use dynamic in any kind of public interface of a class, you should always manually type-check at runtime using reflection, carefully deal with exceptions, or not do it in the first place.

Note: the object being referred to never changes its type, of course. While *obj* may be *object*, the *x* that it refers to is still *SomeType*.

Comment: -1 for saying that `dynamic` is not an actual type (very different from `var` which _isn't_ an actual type, as you correctly say). `dynamic` is most definitely a type in C#, it is even a _static_ type, but an object of type `dynamic` will bypass static type checking. Check out §4.7 of the C# Language Specification or this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Oops, I fixed it. I should have checked first I guess. :D I though dynamic was immediately resolved to the appropriate type on assignment run-time and was never actually typed as "dynamic", but apparently this is not the case.

Comment: By the way, if you run into the ["missing compiler required member"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1630573/missing-compiler-required-member-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-csharpargumentinfo-create) compiler error, you need to add a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that if you use object and you try to access some member of your object it will be a compile time error (because object doesn't have this member). In order to work you need to know what the type is and cast it.

With dynamic you can access any member - no compile time error. If the member doesn't exist at runtime it would be a runtime error. This is the way to go if you know that your heretogeneous objects all have the same member for example.

However if this is the case there is another more clear solution: You can define an interface, with this member and then make all your heretogeneous objects implement it and your list can be `List<IYourInterface>`.

Keep in mind that dynamic's performance might be slightly worse, because of the, well, dynamic type resolution.

Comment: using dynamic, can you check the existence of a member and continue on if it isn't there without throwing an error? kind of like in javascript how you can do something like `if (data.something) {}`?

Comment: This is called reflection. You can use it with or without *dynamic*. Look into GetType(), GetMethod(), etc.

Comment: +1, if you're going down the reflection route, you might as well just use Object (but I'd still recommend the marker interface on top of that)