# Getting a value from dynamic List

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have a list of dynamic and I am trying to get value from a property using reflection. The code goes like this:

```
var list = new List<Employee>();
list.Add(new Employee {FirstName="Krishna"});
IEnumerable<dynamic> data = list;
```

In Employee, lets say I have property called FirstName,

```
 Type type = data.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
 PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty( "FirstName" );
```

Now, how do I get value from this property? I tried:

```
 object value = property.GetValue( data, null );
```

But it gives me error saying object doesnot match target type.

Comment: Check type before using it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379968/listobject-vs-listdynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send to `property.GetValue` function the object you want to get its value

like: `data[0]`

Replace your line with :
`object value = property.GetValue(data[0], null);`
this will return the FirstName of the first element in the list.

Comment: When I use `dynamic data = ` I can do indexing

Comment: but data is of type IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

Here for all the dynamic objects method are same but as you have to access data from list so it looks like as follows :

`data.GetType().GetProperty("visible").GetValue(data[i],null);`

You can do directly Typecast and save in your type data.