# How to work with OData primitives or complex types

Tags: c#, odata

I am working with OData for the first time and have a model entity with the following properties:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Genres { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<string> GenresFiltered { get; set; }
```

When I make the web call to retrieve data from the model I get the following message:

'The property 'Genres' on type 'xxxx' is not a valid property. Properties whose types are collection of primitives or complex types are not supported

Is there a way to workaround this error to display a list of strings in Odata?

Comment: take a look at this and perhaps you want to use a `List<T>` instead 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462921/how-to-create-a-property-for-a-listt

Comment: You may also want to check here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f60c53f-6c73-4c3d-b54d-2a9ba1bcc231/error-properties-whose-types-are-collection-of-primitives-or-complex-types-are-not-supported?forum=adodotnetdataservices

Answer (score 1):

Weird. I wrote a little test web api odata service and it works. The code are as below.

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Foo>("Foos");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

The model class

```
public class Foo
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

The controller class

```
public class FoosController : ODataController
{
    // GET odata/Foos
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(FakeData.GetFoos().AsQueryable());
    }
}
```

And then I tried with `http://localhost:37312/odata/Foos` , the result is

```
{
"@odata.context": "http://localhost:37312/odata/$metadata#Foos",
"value": [
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Genres": [
            "aaa",
            "bbb"
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "Genres": [
            "ccc"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Hope this can help.