# Create generic List property in interface

Tags: c#

I need to make an interface like this:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    List<T> ListA { get; set; }
    List<T> ListB { get; set; }
}
```

And then implement it like this:

```
public class Something01: ISomething
{
    public List<string> ListA { get; set; }
    public List<Person> ListB { get; set; }
}
```

Or like this:

```
public class Something02: ISomething
{
    public List<int> ListA { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListB { get; set; }
}
```

But looking at [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462921/how-to-create-a-property-for-a-listt) it seems like I have to define T in top of my interface class. Which forces me to one specific type for all properties when implementing. Can this be done somehow?

Thanks

Comment: You can make the interface generic too: `public interface ISomething<T>`, but you need 2 generic types to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the interface generic, with a type argument for each property that requires a different type, for example:

```
public interface ISomething<TA, TB>
{
    List<TA> ListA{ get; set; }
    List<TB> ListB {get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class Something01: ISomething<string, Person>
{
    public List<string> ListA { get; set; }
    public List<Person> ListB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Doh I knew this was something right in front of me - thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

> "But looking at other posts it seems like I have to define T in top of
>   my interface class. Which forces me to one specific type for all
>   properties when implementing. "

True. But you may define *as many generic parameters as you want*, not only a single. So in your case this should do it:

```
public interface ISomething<T, S>
{
    List<T> ListA{ get; set; }
    List<S> ListB {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can provide two completely independent types:

```
class MyClass : ISomething<Type1, Type2> { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
public interface ISomething<T, U>
{
    List<T> ListA{ get; set; }
    List<U> ListB {get; set;}
}
```

So when you define your class, it'd be

```
public class Something : ISomething<Person, string>
{
    List<Person> ListA{ get; set; }
    List<string> ListB {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
public interface ISomething<T, K>
  {
    List<T> ListA { get; set; }
    List<K> ListB { get; set; }
  }

  public class Something01 : ISomething<string, Person>
  {
    public List<string> ListA { get; set; }
    public List<Person> ListB { get; set; }
  }
```